In the metric space $ (X,d)$ we have $ \delta>0$ and $B\subseteq\ X :d(x,y)\geqδ$ for all $x \ne y\in\ B $. How can we show that B is closed in X?
Here's what I've tried so far 
$\bullet$ Let $(x_n)\in B:x_n\rightarrow\ x.$ We have to show $x\in\ B.$ However I run into a wall because even if I showed that $d(x_n,x)\geq\ δ$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ that doesn't mean $x\in\ B.$
$\bullet$ What if we show $x\in\ int(B)?$ We'd have to find an $ε>0$ s.t. $B(x,ε)\subseteq\ B$. That seems impossible for a random point since it doesn't hold for any $y\in\ cl(B)$
$\bullet$ Showing $X-B$ is open also seems impossible since we don't have any information on the complement of $B$
$\bullet$Finally, let $x\in\ cl(B)$. We'll show $x\in\ B.$ We know $B(x,ε)\cap\ B\neq\emptyset$ for any $ε>0$. 
That means exactly one of two things: (a) $x\in\ B(x,ε)\cap\ B$ and thus $x\in\ B$ (b) there exists $y\neq\ x$ such that $y\in\ B$ and $d(x,y)< ε$
And that's as far as I managed to get. I'm thinking maybe up next is the equation $cl(B)=B'\cup\ B$ which would mean that either $x\in\ B$ or we somehow exploit the definition of a limit point on x.

Let $y \in X \setminus B$. The ball $B(y, \delta / 2)$ contains at most one element of $X$: If $x, z \in B$ are both in the ball and $x \not= z$ then
$$
\delta \leq d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z) < \delta/2 + \delta/2 = \delta,
$$
which is a contradiction.
If the ball contains no element of $B$ then we're done. Otherwise it contains exactly one such element $x$. But then $B(y, d(y,x)) \subset X \setminus B$, so $X \setminus B$ is open.

Brilliant! Thanks.

First of all, it is impossible to have $d(x,y)\geq\ δ$ for all $x, y \in B$ : $x=y$ gives a contradition. So you should say $d(x,y)\geq\ δ$ for all $x, y \in B$ with $x \neq y$.
If $x_n \to x$ then $d(x_n,x_m) \leq d(x_n,x)+d(x,x_m) \to 0$, which makes  $d(x_n,x_m)<\delta$ for large enough $n$ and $m$. The conlusion now is that the sequence $(x_n)$ is eventually constant, so $x=x_n \in B$ for $n$ sufficently large.
